# Can we remove auto-bold for an entire post?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

Bold on Parenting.SE is applied automatically to all text for a Question *and* Answer after some short period of time, making bold effectively useless for us.  Since when a question is rather new, the bolding isn't applied, those who haven't learned their bolding will be ultimately invisible and use it lose the value of any bold in their question/answer.

Can this be removed as a "feature" on Parenting.SE?

For example, in the answer to [In the USA in the year 2014, does the law forbid children from being out and about without close adult supervision?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14417/in-the-usa-in-the-year-2014-does-the-law-forbid-children-from-being-out-and-abo), the author references what they have bolded, but it is not visually presented differently.

[image]

Now, I guess it is proper to state I am using Chrome to view this site.  Initially questions show up without all text being bold.  It's at some point after being posted that they are in all bold.  I do not see this on SO, but I just checked and I do see the same effect on Writers.SE.  Perhaps this meta is not the correct one to post this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by automatically applied bold text for questions and answers.  Could you please provide some screenshot examples?

Comment: @Beofett I updated the post per your request and added some additional details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this may be an issue with your individual settings, perhaps either in your browser, or in an add-on.

For reference, here is a screenshot I took using Chrome of the same content:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I will investigate and update when I find the source.

Comment: I found the cause.  The Helvetica Neue on my computer is bold by default.  I'll have to adjust that.